# WordPress theme editor not showing

Tags: menus, themes, editor

Why can I no longer see the *Appearance > Editor* function on the left hand menu in WordPress? It won't show up regardless of the theme. It used to be there before though correct? I wanted to add some custom code into the Editor for a particular theme. Did WP stop supporting the Editor function? screenshot attached. TIA!

Comment: What have your tried, code, step by step or a visible screenshot, video is helpful to helps you?

Comment: Editing theme files directly in wp-admin poses a security risk, so some hosts disable it altogether. Your host may have taken away the option. You should check with them, and see the wp-config answer below - if the host allows it that should make the editor appear. However, it is much, much safer to use SFTP when editing files, and also note that if you edit a parent theme directly your edits will be lost as soon as you update the theme - so a child theme is recommended.